# missing semicolon(;) for javascript table?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a table using document.write.
it says I am missing a semicolon

```
var x=3;
var myTable= "<table style='border:4px solid black'><tr><td colspan:3; style='width: 100px; color: red;text-align:center'>Col Head 1</td></tr>";
myTable+="<tr><td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td></tr>";

for (var i=0; i<13; i++) {
myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>"i"</td>";
myTable+="<td style='width:100px;'>*</td>";
myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: center;'>" + i*3 + "</td>";
myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: center;'>" + 7 + "</td></tr>";
}  
myTable+="</table>";

document.write( myTable);
```

I am missing a semi colon here(`myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>"i"</td>";`)

unsure of where it is missing

Comment: In you first myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>"i"</td>"; you need myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>"+ i + "</td>";

Comment: And also var myTable= "<table style='border:4px solid black'><tr><td colspan:3;  you need colspan='3' instead,

Comment: You should have something like `..." + i + "...`, like in your other statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following statement

```
myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>"i"</td>";
```

you haven't used any concatenation to add the value of `i` in the cell. What you need is

```
myTable += "<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>" + i + "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
 myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>"i"</td>";
```

Change with the correct concatenation:

```
 myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>" + i + "</td>";
```

The error said that expected a semicolon due that `"` quotes said to javascript engine that it's a end of a line. When you need a concatenation.